# WordPress parent and child taxonomy by post id

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I want to display the taxonomy terms in custom post type single page by post id like so (Residential / Apartment)
Residential which is the parent
Apartment which is the child
How to get it to display like that by the post id and the taxonomy is "property-type"
I keep getting Apartment only using different ways, maybe because the parent isn't selected in the post editor, how to display it even if it's not selected
Thanks.

Comment: What code do you use to display the term ?

Comment: get_the_term_list(), only returns Apartment but not Parent (Residential)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to manually inject the parents of the terms in the list:

```php
add_filter('get_the_terms', function ($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy)
{
    // Only modify the needed list
    if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'your_post_type' && $taxonomy == 'your_taxnomy' && is_array($terms))
    {
        $terms_with_parents = array();
        foreach ($terms as $term)
        {
            // For each term, check if there is a parent and adds it in the list
            $parent_term = $term->parent != 0 ? get_term_by('id', $term->parent, $taxonomy) : false;
            if (is_object($parent_term) && !is_wp_error($parent_term))
            {
                $terms_with_parents[] = $parent_term;
            }
            $terms_with_parents[] = $term;
        }
        return $terms_with_parents;
    }
    return $terms;
}, 10, 3);
```